# How to print Special Characters on Zebra Printer(ZT410, ZT411CN)

Tags: special-characters, zebra-printers, zpl

When I print this code, no special characters are printed.
Please tell me how to print.
Firmware version is v75.20.14Z

```
^XA
^LL1100
^PW1100
^FT15,70^A0N,70,48^FH^FDITEM:^FS
^FT170,70^A0N,70,48^FD8㎛ * 1226㎜^FS 
^XZ
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlb5s.png)

Can I print after updating to the latest firmware(v92.21.17Z)?
Even when I contracted the Zebra company by phone, they did not give me an accurate answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate Labelry is vs Zebra engines for special characters. You can log into the printer via web browser/IP address, create a file on it's internal flash memory (director) and then render using the printers CPU. Will be better for validating vs Labelry.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print special characters, you need to recall a specific caracter encoding table and then use the FH command to recall the HEX value of the character

have a look here at page 154 for the encoding tables and the CI command to recall them
https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

and here, the first examples shows something similar you're trying to achieve
https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Printing-with-International-Characters?language=en_US